# How does this thread join() work as given?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm a newbie to java and currently working with a training material, where the below code produces the following output:

```
Run. Run. doIt
```

How does it print *Run.* twice? How does the t.join() work?

```
public class TestTwo extends Thread {
    public static void main (String[] a) throws Exception {
        TestTwo t = new TestTwo();
        t.start();
        t.run();
        t.join();
        t.doIt();
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.print("Run. ");
    }
    public void doIt() {
        System.out.print("doIt. ");
    }
  }
```

Comment: What an abomination.  Is that from the Safeway School of Programming?

Comment: I recommend the "cave of programming" vids on threads - https://www.udemy.com/java-multithreading/#lecture/108950

Comment: Why does my comment keep attracting "rude or offensive" flags?  It's not like I'm insulting anyone (except maybe the instructor who wrote that example).  For the record, I'm not generally in favor of trying to teach people good programming by using bad code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Perhaps the example is to show that `start()` calls `run()`, or that `Thread` is still a regular class with methods that can be called, or something. I agree that it's an abomination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`t.start()` starts the execution of the new thread, which will execute the code in `t.run()`. But the call to `t.start()` will return immediately; it won't wait for that thread to finish its execution of `run()`. After `t.start()` returns, the main thread runs `t.run()`. Finally, it'll wait for the `t` thread to finish, which is what `t.join()` does. This method will *not* return immediately, but will instead wait for the thread to finish. (As it happens, that's going to be very fast in this case -- but it could potentially take minutes, hours, or even forever.)

The control flow looks something like this:

```
Thread A
|
+- t.start() ---> starts Thread B
+- t.run()               +- t.run()
|                        |
+- t.join() waits for B  |
|           to finish    |
|               \------> +- Thread B stops
+- t.doIt()
+- Thread A stops
```

Comment: @Bohemian I was being a bit colloquial. Tightened up the language.

Comment: The other thing to note is that calling start() doesn't actually start the thread. It's just a request to the JVM that it *be* started; when it starts is indeterminate.

Comment: @yshavit: Might be a silly question, but this is my understanding: The run() method is a default method for a thread, but can be overridden. So, whenever a thread is started, it automatically executes only run(). Here, after the two run()s are complete, the doIt() is explicitly called, so it runs as well. Is this right? If so, why is run() executed automatically in B, but is explicitly called in A?

Comment: @Bohemian From an OS/JVM-implementation perspective, you may be right. From a Java perspective, it's a distinction that teeters between pedantic, meaningless and wrong. The docs for [Thread.start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) say it "causes this thread to begin execution." JLS § 17 [says in the second paragraph](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html) that "a thread will start when the start() method is invoked on thecorresponding Thread object." Of course, when the first action in `run()` is scheduled is a different question.

Comment: @mankand007 You're correct. But the thing to realize is that even though `run()` is "special" in that it's the method that a new thread will execute, it's _also_ just a normal, run-of-the-mill method that you can explicitly invoke from anywhere and as much as you like. Imagine if I had a method `public void goFoo() { foo(); }`. Invoking `goFoo()` will cause `foo()` to run, but `foo()` is also a normal method that you can invoke explicitly. Same idea.

Comment: @yshavit Consider instantiating 1000 thread objects and calling each thread's start() method in a tight loop. Even on a CPU with a lot of cores, there's no way all threads will "start". Calling start() just makes a request to the JVM to schedule thread execution. You may consider starting 1000 threads an extreme case, but also consider a web server being hit hard and an implementation that executes some business logic asynchronously in a (new) separate thread (poor design maybe, but not inconceivable). The distinction between calling start and *actually* starting is then no longer "trivial".

Comment: @Bohemian How are you defining "start"? None of those threads will return a `getState()` of `NEW` after you invoke `start()` on them. All of them will throw `IllegalThreadStateException` if you try to invoke `start()` on them again. In that extreme case, each call to `start()` may take longer, and even once it returns it make take a while for the first action in `run()` to be invoked; but by the time `start()` returns, (a) nobody else can start the thread and (b) its state will not be `NEW`. Whatever definition of started you have, it  seems at odds with the javadoc and JLS.

Comment: @yshavit: Thanks for the explanation! If run() is also just a normal method that can be called, then in this case, why didn't it run twice for thread A? One because of the t.start(), and other because of the explicit t.run()?

Comment: @mankand007 Because the `t.run()` that's invoked from `t.start()` is within Thread B. Colloquially/informally, `t.start()` says "start the t thread, and _within that thread_, invoke `run()`."

Comment: @yshavit: So, in thread B, run() doesn't have to be called explicitly, because it is part of the start() method.However, in the main thread (A), we need to explicitly call run() for it to run. Am I understanding it right?

Answer (score 1):

```
t.run();
```

is an extraneous call.

When you start the thread with `t.start()` it is started independently. This prints "run" to the screen.

Then, `t.run(` runs the thread's `run(` method which *also* prints `run`. These two prints of "run" can be in either order.

Lastly, we call `t.join`. This waits for the thread to terminate(after its print by design of join, and after the print from run as the `run` call is before and blocking.

After the `join` the doIt function is called in a blocking manner.

In a nutshell, the main and `t` threads both print `run` and then the main thread waits until the `t` thread is finished to print `doIt`.

Although many of the calls are part of `t` threading acts somewhat independently of instances.

Comment: does this mean that even if there is no t.run(), the result will be the same?

Comment: @mankand007 No. One of the `run` outputs will be omitted as the print is never called twice then. Try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

The `start()` method causes the thread object to execute (when it executes is indeterminate), and the JVM calls the `run()` method.

But you also call `run()` directly, that's why `run()` executes twice.

Calling `join()` waits for the thread to die, which happens after its `run()` method has finished.

Comment: This doesn't really answer much.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I thought it was obvious, but I've spelled it out now

Comment: The join ensures that both Run messages are printed before doIt.

Comment: @inc oh yeah... Too early :/

Answer (score 1):

It may also print

```
RRuunn..  doIt
```

Comment: `PrintStream.print` delegates to a private [`PrintStream.write`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.write%28java.lang.String%29), which is synchronized. So unless you replace `System.out` with a custom subclass of `PrintStream` which doesn't synchronize, you won't see this in practice. That's not guaranteed by the `PrintStream` contract, though; it's just a handy "not required, but works in practice" thing.